# How to enumerate 5 colors to array list repeatedly

Tags: android

How can I set 5 colors (not random) to the list like on picture below.
I have 2 arrays, First array is 5 colors and the other is object contain size more than 5. I just need the logic. Thanks

Here's my implementation

```
try {
    for (int i=0; i<response.length(); i++){
        Customer customer = new Customer(response.getJSONObject(i));
        customer.setInitBackground(Util.getAvatarColor(activity).get(Your suggestion));
        activity.customers.add(customer);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image: See image below]

Comment: I've just tried Collections.enumeration(list).nextElement

Answer (score 1):

You have to use hashes limited by the number of colors.

```
Contact contact = getItem(position);
int pos = contact.getName().hashCode() % colors.length;
int color = colors[pos];
```

Comment: Many different variations possible here, you can perform hash code on contact itself instead of the name, or you can get abbreviation from the name and perform hashCode on it.

Comment: @LaurencePardz what's the problem? Do the colors are wrong? Can you show the code you ended up with?

Comment: If you want colors to be repeated always in the same order you can set  `int pos = i % colors.length;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. Thank you to all answers.

```
try {
    for (int i=0; i<response.length(); i++){
        Customer customer = new Customer(response.getJSONObject(i));
        int pos = i % Util.getAvatarColor(activity).size();
        customer.setInitBackground(Util.getAvatarColor(activity).get(pos));
        activity.customers.add(customer);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```